# Change background color for a cell in a QTableModel

Tags: python, c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel, qvariant

I want to color a cell in a `QTableView`.

So  I'm trying to change the `itemData` of the corresponding item in the associated `QTableModel`.

To do so, I use the `setItemData` method of the `QAbstractTableModel` class.

In the documentation :

`QAbstractItemModel::setItemData(const QModelIndex & index, const QMap < int, QVariant > & roles)`

This is my piece of code :

```
color = QtGui.QColor(Qt.red)
self.model.setItemData(self.model.index(3,3),color,Qt.BackgroundRole)
```

I thought this would color the third cell of the model (horizontally and vertically) in red.

But the application answers :

```
TypeError: QAbstractItemModel.setItemData(QModelIndex, dict-of-int-QVariant): argument 2 has unexpected type 'QColor'
```

If I try to transform the `Qcolor` type in a `Qvariant` :

```
color = Qt.QVariant(QtGui.QColor(Qt.red))
self.model.setItemData(self.model.index(3,3),color,Qt.BackgroundRole)
```

Answer :

```
TypeError: PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant represents a mapped type and cannot be instantiated
```

Which I really can't understand.

So there is my question : which type of data must I put in the second parameter of a `setItemData` method?

Thanks for advance

Comment: setItemData doesn't accept color as second index

Comment: Yes, I had misunderstood the documentation. I thought a color was expected, but it was a Qmap.
With setData, the problem is resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `QAbstractItemModel::setData` to set a single value in the [itemData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#itemData) map.

```
self.model.setData(self.model.index(3,3),color,Qt.BackgroundRole)
```

You can use `QAbstractItemModel::setItemData` if you want to set many values at once, but have to build a `QMap` where each couple is composed by a role and its corresponding value:

```
 QMap<int, QVariant> map;
 map.insert(Qt::BackgroundRole, color);
 self.model.setItemData(self.model.index(3,3), map);
```

Comment: Thank you very much p-a-o-l-o!
Thanks to you, I finally understood how setItemData works.
I've used setData, and the error message is gone.
The (3,3) cell has not changed color, but it's another problem! ;-) This one is resolved.